# Creating a cadenza (Boccherini Concerto No 3 in G Maj)

Tags: composition, cello, cadenza

I need to create a cadenza (a virtuoso passage inserted near the end of a concerto movement) for cello for the first part of Boccherini Concerto No 3 in G Maj (Allegro, starting at measure 98 in my score). It must be different from the cadenzas given in the editions.

I'm a little bit dumbstruck about how to start that task.

Is there kind of a standard procedure to do so? How do you start that sort of thing? Do you know of a tutorial for creating such virtuoso passages?

Any help to overcome my inhibition would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer: listen to recordings of cadenzas for this piece and others. If you can't use the written one, then listening to other pieces in a similar style should give you some ideas. From this, you should be able to get a general idea of the style, composition, and length you need to apply. If you hear something you like, copy or modify it.